# Programatically enable/disable pinch to zoom on WKWebView and viewForZoomingInScrollView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView and I want to programatically enable/disable pinch to zoom.

What should I return when I want to enable pinch to zoom?

wkWebView!.scrollView breaks with

> 'The view returned from viewForZoomingInScrollView: must be a subview
>   of the scroll view. It can not be the scroll view itself.'

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

  if pinchToZoom {
    return ???
  } else {
    return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pinchToZoom)
{
    for (UIView *subScrollView in [scrollView subviews])
    {
        if ([subScrollView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"WKContentView")])
        {
            return subScrollView;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
else
{
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: This uses private API and may result in Apple rejecting your app.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to set `self` as `webView.scrollView`'s delegate only when disabling zoom, and reset it to `nil` if zoom is enabled.

```
var pinchToZoom: Bool {
    didSet {
        // only set self as delegate when disabling zoom
        webView.scrollView.delegate = pinchToZoom ? nil : self
    }
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return nil
}
```

This way, as soon as `pinchToZoom` is set, the delegate updates to enable/disable zooming. No private API needed. Hope this helps!